# simulation of lin-log amplification

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, continuous-signals

I struggle with two simple questions.

First. What is the distribution of the signal on the output of the lin-log amplifier if Rayleigh noise is driven to the input of it.

Using an approach with the inverse function it is possible to obtain the expression for the distribution of the output signal. It looks like the First Extreme Value Distribution (i.e. with $\exp(\exp(x))$ pattern). 
In other words, if $f_{in}$ is the input of the lin-log amplifier:
$$
f_{in} = \frac{r}{D}e^{\frac{-r^{2}}{2D}}
$$
one can get $f_{out}$ - the  distribution of the output signal:
$$
f_{out} = \frac{e^{-\frac{e^{2x}}{2D}-2x}}{D}
$$

But I found a statement somewhere in engineers forums that a lin-log amplifier works more trickily and "takes a logarithm of an envelope" and "there were a lot of problems with erroneous simulations of lin-log signal transformation". It was just statements without explanations that gave me feed for thoughts. 
I found experimental data. It looks more like:
$$
f_{out} = \frac{\log(x)}{K_{1}}e^{\frac{-\log(r)^{2}}{K_{2}}}
$$ 
I'm afraid that it is very similar to the First Extreme Value Distribution and they are indistinguishable in an experimental environment. For example, the additional logarithm of both of them results in Gaussian-like distributions and the difference between them are again almost completely indistinguishable.

Second. How to simulate the lin-log amplifier (detector) in R or MATLAB. 
The problem is that taking the logarithm of a random variable with Rayleigh's distribution results in a distribution with a negative skewness which does absolutely not resemble the above-mentioned alternatives expected. The same distribution with a negative skewness one can get using normally distributed in-phase and quadrature components of the signal.

Is there anybody who understands the problem and could share the idea on how to represent the output of the lin-log detector mathematically and simulate it numerically?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe what you are looking for Is detailed in this Agilent app note: https://volpefirm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Agilent-Spectrum-and-Signal-Analyzer-Measurements-and-Noise.pdf

Comment: Thank you, Dan! But this is right the problem with all manuals like that one you referenced to. I've collected some experimental data and see no distributions with a negative skewness like it is illustrated in Figure 6. of the Agilent manual referenced by you. As I wrote, the experimental distribution is more resemble to the third expression I gave in my initial question. In order to be sure that I have Rayleigh signal on the input of a lin-log amplifier, I collected cm-wave radar signals from rains. The latter is seen as a classical case of fluctuations with a Rayleigh distribution.

Comment: Interesting, could you share a link to your data? I have a basic understanding of how log-limiting amplifiers work under the hood having  worked on those designs in my past which is explained well in this link by ADI : https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/logarithmic-amplifiers-explained.html. Can you look at that and tell me if this is identical to your use of "lin-log" amplifier?

Comment: Note that the output of the log limiting amplifier is the limited signal but the detected output (which is proportional to the log of the input signal) is what would be distributed according to the log-Rayleigh distribution. Perhaps this is what is leading to your discrepancy?

Comment: No, I used not log-limiting amplifier. You can find a short consideration of the scheme here https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/the-fundamentals-of-logarithmic-amplifiers in the chapter "The multistage log amp". The functional scheme was very old-fashioned i.e. a lin-detector (as an inividual separated unit) followed by a lin-log amplifier (also a separated unit). The point of starting taking the logarithm laid -20dB below rms of the channel noise.

Comment: You wrote, "Perhaps this is what is leading to your discrepancy". Yes. Perhaps it is the point that was discussed in the engineering forum I mentioned. But I used a signal after the detector, not its limited version. For the former is the main subject in the radar (and I really can not invent the application of the latter off the top of my head now. Most likely it may be something with frequency modulation used in radio communications, but I used a classical radar approach). You may lake a look at the radar, if it is interesting to you: http://www.russianarms.ru/forum/index.php?topic=4581.0

Comment: Here you can find the data collected by fellows from Georgia Institute of technology citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.459.2110&rep=rep1&type=pdf. It was so interesting that I decided to check it once again. My own data is almost the same. It was gathered using a radar mentioned above with the same functional scheme as American used in their days, but my radar operated at about 1.7..1.8 cm wavelength, that is not crucial for the result.

Comment: Yes that topology is exactly what I had in mind when I said "Log Limiting amplifier". See figure 4 in your link specifically. When you say you used the signal after the detector then you used the "Log Envelope Output" and not the "Limiting Amplifer Output"? In this case then I do believe the Log Envelope Output would be distributed very much according to the Agilent App note (this in fact best represents the vertical scale on the spectrum analyzer) if your input signal was indeed white noise (whose magnitude ona  linear scale would be Rayleigh distributed).

Comment: Dan, Fig. 4 is a successive detection log amplifier or in your terms limiting log amplifier. It's just a variant of a practical realisation of a log-amp topology.

Comment: Take a look at Tech Report of Georgia Institute of technology somewhere from page 30 to 40. There you can see histograms of experimental data. All of them are pretty far from well-known Rayleigh's shape. That is the main problem. No one will agree with you if you say that there are a lot of cases when a radar return from rains is not a signal with rayleigh's distribution.

Comment: I am getting confused then--- are you saying that you are not using a successive detection log ampllifier? Also are you pointing out that your experimental data does NOT have a Rayleigh shape? If so, the signal's magnitude at the input to the Log Amp is not Rayleigh distributed? My understanding is that radar returns would be Rayleigh distributed when there are multiple reflections without one dominant one, otherwise the distribtuion is Ricean; is that not your understanding?

Comment: Why are you getting confused? There are two types of a lin-log amplifiers practical topology. All of them imply the usage of saturated diodes to switch on an off an amplifying stage. In the USSR and US, there were even special types of diodes designed to be used in log amplifiers. But it is not the problem, as I see it. Let's assume I used a "Log Envelope Output". And yes, my and American experimental data point out that the output of the lin-log amplifier has not rayleigh's distribution. And yes, there is an obvious conclusion that the input to the Log Amp is not Rayleigh distributed,

Comment: And yes, our understanding of Rayleigh's and Rice's distribution is  the same.

Comment: I am confused because your first question posted above starts off as "What is the distribution of the signal on the output of the lin-log amplifier if Rayleigh noise is driven to the input of it?" But now you are saying that it is not Rayleigh distributed. So what is your first question actually?

Comment: And I have opinions for your second question that it would indeed be well modeled as simply modifying the envelope according to the log of the actual input. Do you have data you can share that shows that is not the case and perhaps the answer can be found in that data?

Comment: Dan, my question is "What is the distribution of the signal on the output of the lin-log amplifier if Rayleigh noise is driven to the input of it"? You accepted the fact about non-rayleigh distribution on the input of log-amplifier too quickly. I wrote that no one would understand and even sympathise you if you are going to say that a scattering signal from rain does not have a Rayleigh distribution.

Comment: You wrote directly above "And yes, there is an obvious conclusion that the input to the Log Amp is not Rayleigh distributed" which I misunderstood as your own conclusion, hence my confusion. My answer and experience both with successive detection log-amps and spectrum analyzers whose vertical scale provide that function is what I provided in my first comment (for all the signal that is within the bandwidth of the log-amp), and I haven't heard a reason yet to change that opinion. Are you not able to review the input data directly to confirm that it is not Rayleigh distributed?

Comment: It would be great if you could post the actual input and output data

Comment: I think the problem lays in the scale of the axis. Take a look at fig. 4 of Agilent's manual you sited. You can see, that the axis has a log scale. Therefore the shape of the distribution has negative skewness. But if your equipment (or processing procedure)  draws (formes) a log-distribution in linear scale, you will have the shape resemble the third expression a gave above.

Comment: You wrote: "Are you not able to review the input data directly to confirm that it is not Rayleigh distributed". How can I do this if I listened to the output of log-amp? If you take my data and form a distribution, you would have the function like my third expression.

Comment: It's the logamp that is changing that scale -- it changes the input in dB to a linear output. Are you able to share your data? Also are you sure in your processing you were taking the log of the magnitude of the envelope not the signal?

Comment: Unfortunately, data has a sophisticated binary format, as it is usual after ADC. It will take time to post it here.

Comment: I see, you do not have access to the input to the log amp only the output I gather. This I did not understand. It's simple to model Rayleigh distributed data, have you tried that experiment to confirm the output matches Figure 6? Also I am not a radar  / rain expert but can see how multiple reflections from all the  drops would clearly be Rayleigh, but what if there is a dominant target also present, wouldn't it then be Ricean?

Comment: Yes I did not have access to the input of the log amp (just like Americans from Georgia institute) because we used old military equipment filled with resin. And we collected tons of data with this equipment.

Comment: You wrote: "but what if there is a dominant target also present, wouldn't it then be Ricean"? What the difference in terms of skewness in log scale?

Answer (score 0):

The distribution of the log magnitude output of a log amplifier would be according to the log of the magnitude of the input. Although in implementation the log amp is not simply taking a log of the input signal, the result is indeed the log with reasonable accuracy (typically linear to the log scale within a fraction of a dB). Below shows how this should appear for both Rayleigh and Ricean distributions. Given the OP is not seeing the same skewness as is the case for the Rayleigh at the log magnitude output of the log amp, I would conclude that the input signal (which he does not have access to) was not Rayleigh distributed.

Notice the skewness decreases significantly as the dominant path in the Ricean distribution (A) becomes more prominent, as would be expected.

[image: Comparative Plots]